# Exception has occurred: ValueError Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d" (type Conv2D)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this error when i try to build this file. Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you a lot. Sorry for my bad english.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2, os
from glob import glob
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K
#K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

def get_image_size():
    img = cv2.imread('gestures/7/32.jpg', 0)
    return img.shape

def get_num_of_classes():
    return len(glob('gestures/*'))

image_x, image_y = get_image_size()

def cnn_model():
    num_of_classes = get_num_of_classes()
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
```

**Error Log:**
[image: Log of Errors]

The Error seems to be in the following line.

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
```

Comment: image_x, image_y = get_image_size(). Here only image_y seems to be populated with image dimensions. image_x will be empty. I think that's causing the issue. Please try to populate image_x with data and try again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The input shape simply too small for  the convolution that is applied in your model.

You can either decrease the Kernel size or apply padding='same' in the Conv2D layer as follows:

- Decreasing Kernel size

  `model.add(Conv2D(16, (1,1), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))`
- Apply padding

  `model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'))`

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!